# Primefaces and RemoteCommand: Best pratice to handle parameters from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have defined two RemoteCommand's like this:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc1" actionListener="#{rcBean.rcActionListener1}" action="#{rcBean.rcAction1}" />

<p:remoteCommand name="rc2" action="#{rcBean.rcAction2}" />
```

The Javascript method call rc1 and rc2 with parameters like this:

```
rc1({a:'value for a', b:'value for b'});

rc2({a:'value for a', b:'value for b'});
```

And the rcBean rcActionListener and rcAction is: [rcBean part of code]

```
protected String param_a, param_b;

protected void processRcParams() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    param_a = (String) map.get("a");
    param_b = (String) map.get("b");
}

public void rcActionListener1() {
    processRcParams();
}

public void rcAction1() {
    //-> parameters setted
    //-> process something...
}

public void rcAction2() {
    //-> parameters not set yet, and so
    processRcParams();
    //-> process something...
}
```

Judging that the parameters are not defined directly in p:remoteCommand (they are passed from JavaScript via rc1 or rc2), if the parameters can be read directly in the action, then the actionListener is not required.

What is the best practice for this: Read the parameters before on the actionListener or directly in the action? and Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            function test(){
                document.getElementById('hiddenurlpage').value = "test1";
                lazyload();

            }
                //]]>
        </script>
<h:inputHidden id="hiddenurlpage" value="#{userBean.currentpage}"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="lazyload"  process="@this,hiddenurlpage" />
```